# Apache HTTP Server reverse proxying from port 80 to port *

Tags: apache, apache2, reverse-proxy, suse

I have a Suse Linux server with a web application listening on Port 51058. 
I want now to use Apache HTTP Server to forward the user from port 80 to this port so that when the user types the url in the Browser the user sees the application on port 51058.
I do not want to use redirection because i must open then also the port 51058. Is it possible to do something like this with Apache HTTP Server? 
If yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to setup a reverse proxy with Apache using the mod_proxy module.
You may use something like this a Virtual Host for port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MyServerHostName

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:51058/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:51058/

</VirtualHost>
```

Here I assume that 51058 is a non-secure(HTTP) port.

Comment: that looks good, but i have not such a folder called /etc/apache2/mod_proxy. Did i somthing wrong while the installation ?

Comment: There is no need for such folder, just a couple of `LoadModule` declarations in order to load mod_proxy module: `LoadModule proxy_module lib/apache/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module lib/apache/mod_proxy_http.so`. You might want to check several tutorials like [this](https://linuxadmin.io/mod_proxy-installation-apache/) in order to find out how to configure your Apache Server.

Comment: Big thangs. Now it works, i only had a problem with the correct modules. I had to install:
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_html
a2enmod proxy_http
now it works exact the i way i want it, big . thangs =) !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Listen port from 51058 to 80 and configure the Virtual host to use port 80

Comment: I can not change the port of the application. It is a SAP System Application, but it will be to far to explain it. The important thing is that this applictaion listen on the 51058 port an i can not change it. Im apologize if it not get clear in the question.

Comment: another alternative would be to make a firewall rule that redirects the port.